# Target Unreachable, 'resposta' returned null - SelectOneRadio

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, primefaces, nullpointerexception

Não estou conseguindo pegar o valor do meu `selectOneRadio`, vem como `null`:

```
<p:dataTable id="exibePerguntas" var="questao" paginator="true"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="2,3,5,10,12" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                value="#{responderSimuladoBean.simulado[0].questoes}">
                <p:column headerText="Perguntas">
                    <br></br>
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{questao.pergunta}"  />

                <p:selectOneRadio id="resposta" style="width:25%"
                    value="#{responderSimuladoBean.resposta.respostaUsuario}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="A" itemValue="A" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="B" itemValue="B" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="C" itemValue="C" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="D" itemValue="D" />
                </p:selectOneRadio>

                    <h:outputText value="#{responderSimuladoBean.resposta.resultado}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>

            <p:commandButton process="@(#exibePerguntas)" id="enviarSimulado"
                value="Enviar Simulado" action="#{responderSimuladoBean.corrigirSimulado}"
                icon="ui-icon-search" iconPos="right" update=":frmCadastroSimulado">
            </p:commandButton>
```

O valor que está vindo `null` é o `value="#{responderSimuladoBean.resposta.respostaUsuario}">`

Segue o erro:

> GRAVE: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /Simulado.xhtml @25,64
>   value="#{responderSimuladoBean.resposta.respostaUsuario}": Target
>   Unreachable, 'resposta' returned null

Mais até agora não consegui identificar o problema.

Segue a minha bean:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class ResponderSimuladoBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3071538719985705117L;

    @Inject
    private SimuladoDAO simuladoDAO;

    @Inject
    private RespostaService respostaService;

    private Resposta resposta;
    private Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
    private List<Simulado> simulado;
    private List<Resposta> respostas = new ArrayList<Resposta>();

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {

        simulado = this.simuladoDAO.buscaPorTodosSimulados();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void corrigirSimulado() throws Exception {
        respostas.clear();

        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) fc.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        Long codigoUsuario = (Long) session.getAttribute("identificaUsuario");
        usuario.setCodigo(codigoUsuario);

        for (Simulado s : simulado) {
            for (Questao q : s.getQuestoes()) {
                this.limpar();
                resposta.setUsuario(usuario);
                resposta.setQuestao(q);
                resposta.setRespostaCorreta(q.getRespostaPadraoPerguntaItem());
                respostas.add(resposta);
            }
        }

        this.respostaService.salvar(respostas);
    }

    private void limpar() {
        this.resposta = new Resposta();
    }

    public List<Simulado> getSimulado() {
        return simulado;
    }

    public List<Resposta> getRespostas() {
        return respostas;
    }

    public Resposta getResposta() {
        return resposta;
    }

    public void setResposta(Resposta resposta) {
        this.resposta = resposta;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro `Target Unreachable, 'resposta' returned null` significa que alguém no caminho retornou `null`, por isso o JSF não consegue recuperar o valor da propriedade, ou seja, ou o `responderSimuladoBean` é `null` (não acho provável) ou o `responderSimuladoBean.resposta` é (acho o provável).

Contudo, acredito que você esteja utilizando o caminho errado no `selectOneRadio`, porque só existe uma resposta no seu Bean.

Acredito que você deveria mudá-lo para algo como:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class ResponderSimuladoBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3071538719985705117L;

    @Inject
    private SimuladoDAO simuladoDAO;

    @Inject
    private RespostaService respostaService;

    // Removi um aqui
    private Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
    private List<Simulado> simulado;
    private List<Resposta> respostas = new ArrayList<Resposta>();

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        simulado = this.simuladoDAO.buscaPorTodosSimulados();

        // Alterei para aqui
        for (Simulado s : simulado) {
            for (Questao q : s.getQuestoes()) {
                this.limpar();
                resposta.setUsuario(usuario);
                resposta.setQuestao(q);
                resposta.setRespostaCorreta(q.getRespostaPadraoPerguntaItem());
                respostas.add(resposta);
            }
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public void corrigirSimulado() throws Exception {
        respostas.clear();

        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) fc.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        Long codigoUsuario = (Long) session.getAttribute("identificaUsuario");
        usuario.setCodigo(codigoUsuario);

        this.respostaService.salvar(respostas);
    }

    // código igual daqui para baixo
```

}

Depois disso, você deveria mudar seu mapeamento no JSF para algo como:

```
        <p:dataTable id="exibePerguntas" var="resposta" paginator="true"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="2,3,5,10,12" paginatorPosition="bottom"
            value="#{responderSimuladoBean.respostas}">
            <p:column headerText="Perguntas">
                <br></br>
                <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{questao.pergunta}"  />

            <p:selectOneRadio id="resposta" style="width:25%"
                value="#{resposta.respostaUsuario}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="A" itemValue="A" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="B" itemValue="B" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="C" itemValue="C" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="D" itemValue="D" />
            </p:selectOneRadio>

                <h:outputText value="#{resposta.resultado}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

        <p:commandButton process="@(#exibePerguntas)" id="enviarSimulado"
            value="Enviar Simulado" action="#{responderSimuladoBean.corrigirSimulado}"
            icon="ui-icon-search" iconPos="right" update=":frmCadastroSimulado">
        </p:commandButton>
```